# Does cloning and writing create data race conditions in Rust?

Tags: rust

If a global variable is being cloned (as implemented within the standard library) while being written to will it create a data race?

Comment: Rust prevents you from doing this in the first place (unless you use a lot of `unsafe`)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If Im asking the question, then I would make the assumption that its within an `unsafe` tag.

Comment: Can you show an example of the code that you believe is creating a data race? That will make it possible to provide a meaningful answer to your question.

Comment: @Its-me Rather than force people to read your mind and make (possibly differing) assumptions, why not add code and specific examples to your question?

Comment: @GManNickG if its not possible to do this w/o an `unsafe` tag. Then theres really no assumption needed. The question simply does not make sense without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloning data involves reading it. Writing to data involves, well, writing it.

We can safely access data in the following ways

- Any number of threads can read data at a given moment, *or*
- One thread can write to data at a given moment, provided no one else is reading or writing

Neither of these conditions applies (we're reading for the `clone` and we're writing at the same time). Therefore, yes, it's a data race.

As pointed out in the comments, Rust forbids data races. You can't so much as look at a global variable in Rust without an `unsafe` block, since it's never safe to do so, by Rust's rules. But if you wrap your code in `unsafe` and don't provide additional protection then yes, this is a data race.